# 4-way Repeated Measures ANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, interpretation, experiment-design

exchangers!

I am struggling with my data analysis for an article I'm writing. I have to following experimental set-up.

1. Instruction (A/B)
2. Group (Alcohol Dependent / healthy Control)  - between subjects facotr
3. Medication (C/D)  -  (between subject Factor)
4. Session (Baseline / Medication) - Within Subject factor

All subjects performed a certain taks, related to evaluating emotional pictures in a certain way (dependent on instruction A or B). Medication was only administered at the medication (2nd) session. Analyses are performed with SPSS v20.

---

I would like to perform separate analyses for Instruction A and B, but the 4-way interaction is not significant (when putting everything in a 4-way repeated measures anova). This mainly says that the effect of Medication*Session does not differ between groups or instruction. If so, can I perform separate analyses for instruction? Instruction A and B are very significantly different (assessed with a t-test, for the baseline session so medication has no efffect on this). I would want to argue that since, these processes are so different it is better to assess the effect of medication, group and session separately for instruction A and B. The problem is that the non-significant 4-way interaction does not support this claim.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Four way interactions are a mess to interpret.

You can do separate analyses regardless of whether the 4 way interaction is significant or not.

You say you are using repeated measures ANOVA - have you checked all the assumptions? They are very often violated and that might affect the results.

Comment: Hi Peter, 

Thanks for you swift reply! The DV is measures on a scale of 0 to 100. Sphericity is not an issue since within factor has only two levels. There are no drop-outs in in the medication session and after the elimination of outliers the DVs are normaly distributed..  So the asssumptions look good! 

It is good to hear that i can break down the analysis with non-significant results as well!

Since instruction is significantly different at baseline, would you consider this argument suffcient to break the analysis down in A and B?

Answer (score 2):

With four factors, the results get very complicated. I'd suggest you step back and clearly articulate what scientific question you are trying to answer, and then try to find a focussed analysis to answer that question.